# How to determine which driver to use for JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans, driver

I ran the following codes in Netbeans attempting to connect to MySQL database.

```
package database_console;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class DBConnect 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try{
            String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase";
            String uName = "root";
            String uPass = "password";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, uName, uPass );
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM counselor";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            rs.next();
            int id_col = rs.getInt("id");
            String first_name = rs.getString("firstName");
            String last_name = rs.getString("lastName");

            String p = id_col + " " + first_name + " " + last_name;
            System.out.println(p);
        }
        catch(SQLException err){
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

I get the following exception message:

`No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase`

I know that I have to go to my project folder and add a JAR in my libraries folder. I've read through numerous online guides, however none talks about how to determine which JAR file is suitable.

**So my question here is:** Can I just get any JAR file and use it as a client driver? For example `derbyclient.jar`? If not, is there any way to identify which JAR file is suitable to use as a client driver?

**EDIT:** Furthermore, I am a little confused whether I should download the required driver from `Sun Microsystem`, `Netbeans`, `MySQL`.

Comment: Get the driver from the vendor of the databse you use. In your case [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

Comment: I wonder how you'd get the idea that you would be able to use the Derby JDBC driver to talk to MySQL. To me it seems rather obvious that it won't work.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am very new to database connection, this que may seemed easy or obvious to you. But it is quite confusing for someone new, especially with so many possible source to get the driver. Maybe you can reply your solution below?

Comment: No, there are not many sources to get the driver. To get the MySQL driver you go to the MySQL website. To get the Oracle driver you go to the Oracle website. To get the PostgreSQL driver you go to the PostgreSQL website. etc. etc. Its just as clear as that you go to the nVidia website to get a driver for your nVidia videocard, you don't go try and installing AMD drivers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have encountered this error and this is how i solved it.

1)Go to Properties of your project

2)Go to Libraries

3)Add Library

4)Select MySQL JDBC Driver

This worked for me.

Comment: It worked. thanks! I wondered why can't they make these subtle settings automated.

Comment: Sure, just let me see whether more are coming in :)

Answer (score 2):

Go to your netbeans->Project->Properties.
In the libraries "Add Library".
Select MYSQL JDBC Driver.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a JAR in your classpath.

For Mysql, for e.g.- `mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar`

If you are using maven, dependency in POM.xml would be

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.18</version>
</dependency>
```

You need to register a driver, before getting connection using `DriverManager.getConnection` as follows

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Comment: The JAR file should be extracted after I install the msi file am I right? However after I double clicked the msi file and presumably with the installation done, the JAR file is no where to be found. Is there something I did wrongly? Thanks.

Comment: No need to install msi, you directly get JAR.

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC driver is a connector specific to the database. In your case, you'll need the MySQL JDBC connector.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the kind of database you are connecting to while preparing the host url.
In the example pasted 
`String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase";` The string "mysql" indicates its a mysql database. Hence you need to use mysql client library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide based on the Database that you have used.

In your case you have used MySQL so you need to use jdbc driver for MySQL.
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

If you are using Oracle then you can use jdbc driver provided by Oracle.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

You can find jdbc driver on your chosen DB's official website. It is dependent on the JDK version as well as DB version.

Comment: I downloaded the `mysql-connector-java-gpl-5.1.31.msi` from MYSQL website and ran it. The progress bar shows up in a split second and gone. I supposed the installation is done. However I can't find any .jar file nor any new files added in my C: drive. But the online guide says there will be a .jar file. Is there something I miss out ?

Comment: go to http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ and then select "platform independent" in the select platform drop down. Then you need to sign in using Oracle account(if you don't have create one. it's free). Then download the .zip version in which you can find jar file.